# Handle outside click closes on clicking the modal itself. Basically shouldn't close when clicked anywhere but outside of the modal

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

This code has worked for me before but i'm not sure what's changed in this other component i'm trying to use it in.

I've tried using hooks to open and close modal and just plain on click event listener but both times it closes on clicking anywhere on the page.

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.handleOutsideClick);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleOutsideClick);
  }

  handleOutsideClick = (e) => {
    if (this.state.showInfoModal && !this.node.contains(e.target)) this.handleInfoToggle();
    console.log(this.state.showInfoModal, e.target, this.node, 'clicked outside');
  }

  handleInfoToggle = (event) => {
    const { showInfoModal } = this.state;

    if (event) event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ showInfoModal: !showInfoModal });
  };

renderSomething = (args) => {
 return(
   <span ref={(node) => { this.node = node; }}>
   {something === true && <span className={styles.somethingelse}> 
   <HintIcon onClick={this.handleInfoToggle} /></span>}
    <Modal visible={showInfoModal} onCancel={this.handleInfoToggle}>
     some information to show
    </Modal>
   </span>
  )
}

render() => {
  return (
   {this.renderSomething(args)}
  )
}
```

Not sure if this is enough info. but this is driving me nuts.

I also tried adding a dontCloseModal function that someone had suggested:

```
  dontCloseModal = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({
      showInfoModal: true
    });
  }

 <div onClick={this.dontCloseModal}></div>
```

(((this would go around the `<Modal/>` component )))

```
  const refs = React.createRef(); // Setup to wrap one child
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    const isOutside = () => {
      return !refs.current.contains(event.target);
    };
    if (isOutside) {
      onClick();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

    return function() {
      document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
    };
  });

  return (element, idx) => React.cloneElement(element, { ref: refs[idx] });
}

export default ClickOutside;
```

Tried using a component like this ^^ and adding `<ClickOutside onClick={this.closeInfoModal()}></ClickOutside>`
But same issue with this too- closes on click anywhere including inside modal

Comment: which library did you import Modal from?

Comment: I used `react-modal` but that's the parent modal which is being used in another modal called <Content /> Which is what i'm using for the Modal. i hope i make sense. The issue is, its working flawlessly in another modal in the app but something is different here which closes the modal on clicking anywhere on the page.

Comment: have you considered adding `shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={false}` to the modal for example `<Modal shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={false} />` this prevents closing the modal from outside the modal component

Comment: Hi @trailblazer - Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54633645/4490712

Comment: @jank thanks! this did solve my problem but now i cannot close the modal on clicking the `x` button within the modal :(

Answer (score 6):

After playing with this a little bit, it seems that you should also `useRef` here.
This will allow you to control toggling the modal if the user clicks outside and inside the modal's target.

There are a lot of sophisticated ways to achieve this. However, since we are dealing with hooks here, it would be best to use a custom hook.

Introducing `useOnClick`:

```
// Custom hook for controling user clicks inside & outside
function useOnClick(ref, handler) {
    useEffect(() => {
        const listener = event => {
            // Inner Click: Do nothing if clicking ref's element or descendent elements, similar to the solution I gave in my comment stackoverflow.com/a/54633645/4490712 
            if (!ref.current || ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
                return;
            }
            // Outer Click: Do nothing if clicking wrapper ref
            if (this.wrapperRef && !this.wrapperRef.contains(event.target)) {
                return;
            }

            handler(event);
        };
        
        // Here we are subscribing our listener to the document
        document.addEventListener("mousedown", listener);

        return () => {
            // And unsubscribing it when we are no longer showing this component
            document.removeEventListener("mousedown", listener);
        };
    }, []); // Empty array ensures that effect is only run on mount and unmount
}
```

Watch this [Demo in CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-modal-j2q4k) so you can see how this is implemented using hooks.

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: thanks for spending time to explain after each action! I'm fairly new to programming and understanding could be challenging at times. 

With the solution you provided, I can't close when clicked outside of modal. I must confess i haven't refactored it in my app yet but from the sandbox, it doesn't work.

Comment: @trailblazer - it is very simple to do that. There are two conditions in this hook.. If you’ll eliminate the second ’if statement (which controls outer clicks) then you will enable the user to close the modal when he clicks outside its area.

Comment: I have updated my demo so it’ll match your description @trailblazer

Comment: thank you !! Turned out, the modal component was the issue. so instead of using a custom modal, i used react-modal directly and combining that with your solution, solved my problem!

Comment: I am facing this issue again :\ This time it is a larger sized modal, so when I click on the left part of modal content, it closes. I used the clientWidth like this
`if (isModalOpen && e.clientX <= e.target.offsetWidth) this.handleModalToggle();`
The modal is 2 components deep and i have multiple modals in the page. Any ideas what I can do ?

I know the issue (its the e.target.offsetWidth) which is not covering the entire modal!

Comment: also, it depends on my window size. If width of window is > 1980px, no problem